# how to specify hard drive size in macstadium orka?

Tags: continuous-integration, orka

How do you change the disk size of your vm in macstadium orka?

Documentation only shows ram and cpu

https://orkadocs.macstadium.com/docs/example-cli-workflows

Answer (score 1):

MacStadium support:

There is no way to increase the hard drive after you create an image. 
To create a custom hard drive with base ISO from scratch, follow the work flow:
https://orkadocs.macstadium.com/docs/orka-image-management

It is during the step:

```
orka image generate
```

[image]